# Method of DialogFragment instantiated in mainActivity.runOnUiThread method returns null but dialog is shown

Tags: android

Inside my SSHsocket class (not extending or implementing anything) I instantiate HandlerThread:

```
        socketHandlerThread = new HandlerThread(sessionTag);
        socketHandlerThread.start();
```

Then I call connect() method:

```
socketHandler = new Handler(socketHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             switch (msg.what) {
               case TerminalService.SERVICE_TO_SOCKET_DO_CONNECT:
                        try {
                            connect();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Message statusMsg = Message.obtain(null,SOCKET_TO_SERVICE_STATUS_DEAD, sessionDetailData.getUuid());
                            serviceHandler.sendMessage(statusMsg);
                            Log.e("SSH Socket id:" + sessionDetailData.getUuid() + " fails. ", e.toString());
                        }
                        break;
```

Inside the connect() method I need to open a yes/no dialog:

```
final String titleMessage = "Do you want to accept the hostkey (type " + algo + ") from " + host + " ?\n";


 mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=mainActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    AcceptKeyDialog acceptKeyDialog = new AcceptKeyDialog();
                    acceptKeyDialog.show(fragmentTransaction, "KEY_ACCEPT_DIALOG");
                    acceptKeyDialog.getTitleView().setText(titleMessage);
                }
            });
```

What happens is that dialog is populated as expected even with buttons. But when debugging it then breakpoints which are (anywhere) inside of runOnUiThread() show attributes of acceptKeyDialog fragment instance being null (inflated views, listener.. I call it controller etc.). So obviously calling the getTitleView() method of AcceptKeyDialog also returns null.

```
public class AcceptKeyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private View keyDialogView;

    //inner listener class for buttons
    private AceeptKeyDialogFragmentController controller;

    private TextView title;
    private Button yesButton;
    private Button noButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));

        //DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE is not working as it should
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        controller = new AceeptKeyDialogFragmentController();
        keyDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.accept_key_dialog, container, false);
        title = (TextView) keyDialogView.findViewById(R.id.accept_key_title);
        yesButton = (Button) keyDialogView.findViewById(R.id.accept_key_yes_button);
        noButton = (Button) keyDialogView.findViewById(R.id.accept_key_no_button);

        title.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        yesButton.setOnClickListener(controller);
        noButton.setOnClickListener(controller);

        return keyDialogView;
    }

    public TextView getTitleView(){
        return title;
    }

    private class AceeptKeyDialogFragmentController implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.accept_key_yes_button:

                    break;
                case R.id.accept_key_no_button:

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I thought this might be better than using handler messages(or handler.post.. or by passing runnable in the message) but obviously I missed something fundamental in the HandlerThread concept. I thought also that it might be something related to passed reference of mainActivity which is done by `mainActivity=(MainActivity)msg.obj`

But I don't see activity status being changed (monitoring MainActivity onStop() method)

```
@Override
    protected void onStop(){
        Log.e("MainActivity is in onStop state","");
        super.onStop();
    }
```

The final goal is to pass user decision back to worker thread and it continues based on response. Can you advice please?

Answer (score 0):

I've earned Tumbleweed badge on this question so it deserves an answer :)
However the answer might be sort of disappointing as I don't have full understanding of it. What I've described seems to be general problem related to Main Thread object backward visibility inside another thread where the mainActivity.runOnUiThread() method runs. As you can I see below I don't instantiate a dialog object. Instead I run in Main Thread method activity.fireInteractiveDialog(args) which does this for me.
So I had to stop the thread in order to get user input and then wait for an condition(as well as the input itself) making the thread running again. It was all done by "guarded lock" programming construct and of course instance of HandlerThread() was the thread delivering the condition state and notified stopped thread to run again. 
Here is the code:

```
public synchronized void getUserInput() {


            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("somethingDialogTag", tag);
                    args.putString("somethingDialogTitle", title);
                    args.putStringArray("somethingDialogContent", content);
                    args.putBoolean("somethingDialogPassword", isPassword);
                    if (isPassword) {
                        args.putString("somethingDialogExistingPassword", sessionDetailData.getPassword());
                    }
                    //lets open the dialog
                    activity.fireInteractiveDialog(args);

                }
            });


            while (!isInputAvailable) {
                try {
                    Log.d("Thread " + String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), " going to wait.");
                    wait();
                    Log.d("Thread " + String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), " has woke up.");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

And inside the same class the HandlerThread changed (as carried by a Message object) variable isInputAvailable as well as provided user input once it was ready.

```
socketHandlerThread = new HandlerThread(tag);
socketHandlerThread.start();

socketHandler = new Handler(socketHandlerThread.getLooper()) {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                switch (msg.what) {
                    case Bus.SERVICE_TO_SOCKET_STATUS_KEY_ACCEPTANCE:
                        isKeyAccepted = ((MessageHolder) msg.obj).getLogic();
                        synchronized (advancedVerifier) {
                            advancedVerifier.notifyAll();
                        }
                        Log.e(tag + "User decided to accept key", String.valueOf(((MessageHolder) msg.obj).getLogic()));
                        break;
```

I hope it helps somebody someday. It would be great if somebody understanding the object visibility across the threads(Android main thread and workers) responds.